# Trying to clone my old drive to a newer one, but everything I have tried is either too slow or just quits

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, clone, copy

I am trying to clone a 2tb external drive to another 2tb external drive, the original drive has many corrupted files (due to bad reads) and results in CRC (cyclic redundancy check) errors, which either stop, or severely slow down any copy method I have tried. Additionally it is very likely the copy will be interrupted midway through either from loss of connection to the drive or power issues, so whether it's cloning or copying, it needs to continue where it left off.

I do not want to check for errors, as they always happen in the same places and checking for them will not change anything in terms of data copied over, I don't need to get everything off the drive, just as much as I can, so I don't care if it copies over bad files.

PLEASE do not tell me to try robocopy/copy/xcopy with the /r:0 or /e args (these still check for errors); I have tried Roadkil's unstoppable copier (it technically works, but is far too slow to finish in a reasonable amount of time); I have tried some disk cloning softwares that claim to be able to continue after encountering bad sectors (AOMEI and Macrium) but they just quit when they encounter errors; I have taken a look at a custom script that claims to copy files bit for bit and filling with all 0s if an error is detected, but that only works on single files (the drive has likely over a million files.) I am trying FreeFileSync, but that so far just stalls a lot (this is the most promising though.

This is on Windows 10, although I have the option to use a Mac if necessary

Comment: `it technically works, but is far too slow to finish in a reasonable amount of time` .. this is the nature of copying from a drive with bad blocks.  I have had a computer take WEEKS to copy a corrupt drive.  Mac won't help.  If anything I would say `ddrescue` would be your best bet but you will need to boot to a Linux Live disk to get to it.  Mac *might* have it but I wouldn't trust the version or BSD flavor for a tool like this.  It TOO will take A LONG TIME.  The windows version of `ddrescue` (and `dd`) are not the same.  Info on [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) here.

Comment: There isn’t a fast solution to your problem. You could try a hardware based HDD cloner but that likely will have unpredictable results due to the bad sectors. The time for backups, was a routine backup, that could be used it’s nearly to late when the storage device already had bad sectors

Comment: @Señor CMasMas by "reasonable amount of time" I mean under a couple months, thats how slow it is, and most of the time its not even reading from the drive, just waiting. robocopy would take nearly 6 months and roadkil's copier would take around 3 months. Weeks would be a blessing. I am trying FreeFileSync and that seems to be working so far, but its still only in the scanning phase and hasnt actually copied anything yet.

Comment: Please clean up the layout, a "wall of text" is not very appreciative of your fellow readers. Thank you!